# DataGridView need to be exported into an excel file

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

My Program contains a datagridview and the user fills it up with the data manually during runtime. When the user clicks save I wish to export the datagridview to an excel file that they can access later.

The code I have at the moment comes up with an error type "Null Reference Exception"

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()

    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!")
        Return
    End If


    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
    'xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet 1 content"
    'xlWorkSheet.Cells(3, 3) = "Sheet 1 content"

    If ((DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0) Or (DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0)) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If



    For k As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k + 1) = DataGridView1.Columns(k).HeaderText
    Next
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1

            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()

        Next
    Next



    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\test\DATAGRID.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
     Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
    xlWorkBook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlApp)

    MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file C:\test\DATAGRID.xls")
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any reason you are using System.Reflection.Missing.Value instead of Nothing?

Comment: for some reason i had some problems when I tried to save it using Nothing so I tried this instead, the code works without the code for the rows under the header text. so the saved file only contains the headers of my datagridview

Comment: What is the value of DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()? Is it empty?

Comment: Which line, exactly, throws the exception?

Comment: DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString() throws the exception

Comment: It can be empty depending on whether the user decides to fill that spot

Comment: The problem is that you are accessing the data incorrectly on DataGridView1. You should do DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Guys for the help

I found this bit of code that actually does what I want

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rowsTotal, colsTotal As Short
    Dim I, j, iC As Short
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value


    Try
        Dim excelBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(excelBook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

        rowsTotal = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        colsTotal = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        With excelWorksheet
            .Cells.Select()
            .Cells.Delete()
            For iC = 0 To colsTotal
                .Cells(1, iC + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Columns(iC).HeaderText
            Next
            For I = 0 To rowsTotal - 1
                For j = 0 To colsTotal - 1
                    .Cells(I + 2, j + 1).value = DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(j).Value
                Next j
            Next I
            .Rows("1:1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
            .Rows("1:1").Font.Size = 10
            .Cells.Columns.AutoFit()
            .Cells.Select()
            .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
            .Cells(1, 1).Select()
        End With
        excelBook.SaveAs("C:\test\DATAGRID.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
   Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file C:\test\DATAGRID.xls")




    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Export Excel Error " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        'RELEASE ALLOACTED RESOURCES
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
        xlApp = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: See my comment above... this does the same thing as your code in the question above, except that it accesses the DataGridView's cell values properly.

Answer (score 1):

When you access the cells of a DataGridView, it functions differently than the Excel interop object. Instead of using:

```
DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
```

You should use:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
```

The Excel interop object simply uses the column and row as an index, but the DataGridView (and most other .NET data objects) store them as nested collections.